# Visual Studio 2022 Resharper can not resolve symbol

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2022, project-reference

I use Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 LTSC 17.2 with ReSharper 2023.1. I work with several projects in one solution and many of them are referenced (we use custom build tool). Visual studio detects them well but ReSharper says that it can not resolve symbol and colors the referenced types red.

Tried ReSharper Suspend / Resume, clearing caches but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

After some trying I managed to solve this problem.

Options -> ReSharper -> Options -> Environment -> General -> Read solution model directly from project/solution files. -> disable checkbox

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).